# convert list of tuple into tuple of list in OCaml

Tags: list, recursion, tuples, ocaml

I want to convert list of tuple into tuple of list, and the first list of tuple consist of the first element of original tuple element.
For example

```
    convert [(1,2);(3,4);(5,6)] = ([1;3;5],[2;4;6])
```

like this.

I tried several times and success to get [1;3;5] by following below code.

```
    let rec convert lst = 
    match lst with
    |[]->[]
    |(a,b)::tl->a::(convert tl)
```

However I have no idea how to get second list element of tuple  [2;4;6] and how to merge them in one tuple.

Comment: The solution you're working on won't be tail recursive and there's a way to do it in a tail recursive way. Try to finish yours with the help of @PatJ's answer and then try do it tail recursive, it's actually easy and a nice training. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way is to use the standard library's `List.split` which does exactly what you want your `convert` function to do.

Now, if this is part of an exercise, I'm not going to give you the whole solution, but here are a few pointers.

First, you must return a tuple of list. Evidently, the matching of the empty list must return a pair of empty lists.

Now, as for the tricky part, assuming you have `(a,b)::tl`, getting `convert tl` first is obviously a thing to do. What can you do if you write in `let (tla,tlb) = convert tl`? Can you solve it now?

Comment: I tried to get this about an hour and finally solve it! thanks a lot